# how to print null value from javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have data from php variable :

```
$data['value'] = [null, 24.5, 22.5, null, 30.1];
```

I convert it into javascript using this code :

```
var newData = <?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
```

I get output like this : `, 24.5, 22.5,, 30.1`

anyone can tell what's wrong with my code?

**UPDATE**

PHP variable :

```
$data['value'][] = null;
$data['value'][] = 24.5;
$data['value'][] = 22.5;
$data['value'][] = null;
$data['value'][] = 30.1;

$data['value2'][] = 20.5;
$data['value2'][] = 19.5;
$data['value2'][] = 30.1;
$data['value2'][] = null;

    echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

output : `{"value":[null, 24.5, 22.5, null, 30.1],"value2":[20.5,19.5,30.1,null]};`

JAVASCRIPT :

```
var newData = <?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

document.write(newData['value']);
```

output : `, 24.5, 22.5,, 30.1`

i need javascript output to be like this : `null, 24.5, 22.5, null, 30.1`

Comment: As `null` is not numeric, it's can't be converted to a number. Should be glaringly obvious from `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`

Comment: any idea how can i include `null` value as output?

Comment: "I get output like this " - no you [don't](https://3v4l.org/LOr5t)

Comment: @georg I thought the same (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43181207/3578036)), but I think the problem is that when using something like `alert` it isn't showing the null values (naturally).

Comment: @JustCarty yes this may be the case as well. However, the thing is, you also need to deal with null values to identify with some another value from php itself. I guess.

Comment: @Mittul At TechnoBrave i have added more code, please take a look

Comment: @TnRobi you can follow my answer below. It will help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Mittul At TechnoBrave can i use array_walk without the key? something like this `array_walk($data, 'x')` so i can acces all data in javascript like this `alert(newData['value'])` because i get output `undifined` if i not use the key.

Comment: try this `array_walk_recursive($data, 'x');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not trying to encode the array correctly.

Since the array you were using was actually stored in `$data["value"]` and not `$data` it meant that you were not creating the array correctly in JavaScript.

```
var newData = <?php echo json_encode($data["value"], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
```

### Following edit

```
<?php
$data[] = [null, 24.5, 22.5, null, 30.1];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($data); $j++)
        if ($data[$i][$j] === null) $data[$i][$j] = "null";
?>
<script>
var newData = <?php echo json_encode($data[$i], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
</script>
<?php } // end for ?>
```

Comment: thank @JustCarty, your solution work. but i make litle change by adding double quote for null data without looping, like this `$data[] = ["null", 24.5, 22.5, "null", 30.1]`

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were able to change the array code so I thought I'd add the loop in. Glad I could be of service :)

Comment: @JustCarty just curious to know, why using for-loop and all when php is already giving us functions like `array_walk` and `array_walk_recursive`, it is doing the same in my answer which you did using for-loop. Can you explain the difference why we should use this instead of these 2 in-built functions ?

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave I may be wrong, but efficiency is the one of the reasons. The two for loops run slightly faster than the `array_walk` does.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_walk` to go over every item in the array and turn them to string if they are null.

```
<?php 

$data['value'] = [null, 24.5, 22.5, null, 30.1];
function x(&$el) {
    $el = ($el === null) ? 'null' : $el;
}
array_walk($data['value'], 'x'); 


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var newData = <?php echo json_encode($data['value'], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
    alert(newData);
</script>
```